# Using Try Catch Exception handling or explicit checks

Tags: java, android, exception

I am developing an android service and coming across two different styles to write code to handle validations.

**First Style**: Using boolean or explicit checks. In this method, I return the whatever values I get from functions. Returned values could be null, Closed (not valid).

```
boolean fbConnected = appPrefences.isFBConnected();
if (!fbConnected)
{
    ShowNotification("FB not connected");
    stopSelf();
    return;
}

Session session = GetSession();
if (session.isClosed())
{
    ShowNotification("Session not valid");
    stopSelf();
    return;
}

Coordinates result = getLocation();
if(result == null)
{
    ShowNotification("Could not get location");
    stopSelf();
    return;
}

//  Do something finally with Session, FB and location
```

**Second Style**: Using Exception handling. Here, I throw my own custom exception from utility methods if the session is closed (invalid) or if the location is null. And I handle it as follows:

```
try
{
    appPrefences.connectToFb();
    Session session = GetSession();
    Coordinates result = getLocation();
}
catch(FBException e)
{
    ShowNotification("FB not connected");
    stopSelf();
    return;
}
catch(SessionException e)
{
    ShowNotification("Session not valid");
    stopSelf();
    return;
}
catch(LocationException e)
{
    ShowNotification("Could not get location");
    stopSelf();
    return;

}

//  Do something finally with Session, FB and location
```

In my view the first one is better, for the reason below:

- In second method, Throwing exceptions incurs performance hits.

Is it OK to use the first method or there are some real benefits to use the second method ?

Answer (score 4):

Use exceptions to

- signal that the caller violates the preconditions for calling the function. This should usually lead to a fix in the programm, because it is the responsibility of the caller to ensure that the preconditions are met.
- signal that the postconditions cannot be ensured by the function despite the fact that the preconditions for calling the function are fulfilled. This should be handled gracefully by the caller.

I think a function like `isFBConnected` should check whether facebook is connected. There are two perfectly valid answers: Yes, No. An exception should be thrown if the function is not able to determine whether facebook is connected.

Answer (score 3):

The use of try/catch blocks in normal program flow incurs a performance hit.  It's better to use the if/then statements in the first example.

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/189222/are-exceptions-as-control-flow-considered-a-serious-antipattern-if-so-why

This is mentioned in [Effective Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683).  Exceptions are, as their name implies, to be used only for exceptional conditions; they should never be used for ordinary control flow.

Answer (score 2):

Agreed with Raúl's answer. I would add that Exceptions are useful when you develop code to be used by other such as libraries or sdk's. Explicit exceptions provide useful feedback and can save a lot of debugging time, especially if they don't have access to source code.

For example, if you develop a special `Layout` in Android that requires exaclty to childviews to work, then you can throw an exception saying "Exactly two children required" so the user is not stuck with a crypric crash and knows what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me the first method is OK, since you're not doing anything really Exception-wise except catching it

Answer (score 1):

There is a performance overhead for generating, throwing, and catching an exception. Definitely in low-level code that might be executed frequently, you don't want to be generating and catching a lot of unnecessary exceptions for standard operation.